# How to properly use the asynchronous libusb?

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, libusb

I worked on the synchronous libusb in my Qt project with good results and now I need the asynchronous features of this library. I understood reading [here](http://libusbx.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__asyncio.html#asyncevent), [here](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Ehjelmn/libusb_hotplug_api/mtasync.html) and [here](https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2015/02/asynchronous-bulk-transfer-using-libusb.html) that, after I've registered my callback function using the `libusb_fill_control_transfer` and submitted a transfer with  `libusb_submit_transfer` , I need to "keep live" the `libusb_handle_events_completed` inside a while loop to get the transfer related events since the libusb doesn't have its own thread. for example you can read a code like this

```
libusb_fill_control_transfer(transfer, dev, buffer, cb, &completed, 1000);
libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);
while (!completed) {
    libusb_handle_events_completed(ctx, &completed);
}
```

Now if I want read a packet that I don't know when it occurs, I think that goes against the asynchronous nature submit a read and wait in the while with  `libusb_handle_events_completed` until the event is triggered.

Then, do I need to create a separate thread within the `libusb_handle_events_completed` in an infinite while loop?

Can anyone, with experience in the asynchronous features of libusb library, give some suggestions on the right approach to handle the transfer events?